# hotelbed API http error

Tags: php, api

Here below i have attached my api request

```
$apiKey = "XXXX";
$Secret = "XXX";
$endpoint = "https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/hotel-api/1.0/hotels";
$request = new http\Client\Request("POST",
$endpoint,
[ "Api-Key"     => $apiKey,
  "X-Signature" => $signature,
  "Accept"      => "application/xml" ]);
try
{  $client = new http\Client;
$client->enqueue($request)->send();
 $response = $client->getResponse();
if ($response->getResponseCode() != 200) {  
   printf("%s returned '%s' (%d)\n",

       $response->getTransferInfo("effective_url"),

       $response->getInfo(),
       $response->getResponseCode()
   );
} else {
  printf($response->getBody());
}
} catch (Exception $ex) {
printf("Error while sending request, reason: %s\n",$ex->getMessage());
}'
```

getting following error

> Uncaught Error: Class 'http\Client\Request' not found in

Comment: remove `'` from EOL of $endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a use statement.

```
use http\Client\Request;

$request = new Request(blah blah);
```

Of course I assume you are using Composer autoloader. If not, you will also need to `require_once()` the file.

Comment: i didn't use any Composer  autoloader. got this code from api provider

Comment: If you don't use autoloading, you'll need to manually require in all the class files you will use. `require_once '/path/to/Request.php; use http\Client\Request;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using cURL instead of pecl_http. Here is an example:

```
<?php

// Your API Key and secret
$apiKey = "yourApiKey";
$Secret = "yourSecret";

// Signature is generated by SHA256 (Api-Key + Secret + Timestamp (in seconds))
$signature = hash("sha256", $apiKey.$Secret.time());

$endpoint = "https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/hotel-api/1.0/status";

echo "Your API Key is: " . $apiKey . "<br>";
echo "Your X-Signature is: " . $signature . "<br><br>";

// Example of call to the API
try
{
    // Get cURL resource
    $curl = curl_init();
    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Accept:application/json' , 'Api-key:'.$apiKey.'', 'X-Signature:'.$signature.'']
    ));
    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);

    // Check HTTP status code
    if (!curl_errno($curl)) {
      switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
        case 200:  # OK
          echo "Server JSON Response:<br>" . $resp;
          break;
        default:
          echo 'Unexpected HTTP code: ', $http_code, "\n";
          echo $resp;
      }
    }

    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);


} catch (Exception $ex) {

    printf("Error while sending request, reason: %s\n",$ex->getMessage());

}
?>
```

Just make sure that first you uncomment *;extension=php_curl.dll* in your php.ini file and restart your server.
We are planning to update our examples in the developer portal because some are outdated or not well documented.